# Sort and get first record in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to sort XML and get first record after sorting.

I have XML as below

```
 <book>
    <book>
        <auther>bell</auther>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-07-22T09:51:48.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <code>999</code>
        <date>2019-07-30T00:00:00.000</date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <auther>bell</auther>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-01-01T09:51:48.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <code>112</code>
        <date>2020-01-30T00:00:00.000</date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <auther>apple</auther>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-02-02T10:09:40.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <code>112</code>
        <date>2018-07-10T00:00:00.000</date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <auther>google</auther>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2020-01-29T09:51:48.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <code>999</code>
        <date>2019-07-30T00:00:00.000</date>
    </book>
</book>
```

I want to sort xml by sorting code ascending, date ascending and get last record (the greatest lastModifiedDateTime)  if there are same "Code" and "date"

This is my expected result

```
   <book>
        <book>
            <auther>apple</auther>
            <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-02-02T10:09:40.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
            <code>112</code>
            <date>2018-07-10T00:00:00.000</date>
        </book>
        <book>
            <auther>bell</auther>
            <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-01-01T09:51:48.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
            <code>112</code>
            <date>2020-01-30T00:00:00.000</date>
        </book>
        <book>
            <auther>google</auther>
            <lastModifiedDateTime>2020-01-29T09:51:48.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
            <code>999</code>
            <date>2019-07-30T00:00:00.000</date>
        </book>
    </book>
```

I tried this code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select = "book">
                <xsl:sort select='code' order="ascending"  data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select='date' order="ascending" />
                <xsl:sort select='lastModifiedDateTime' order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I can get just only one record.

this is actual record.

```
<book>
   <book>
       <auther>apple</auther>
       <lastModifiedDateTime>2019-02-02T10:09:40.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <code>112</code>
        <date>2018-07-10T00:00:00.000</date>
    </book>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly (big IF!), you want to **group** the records by `code` and `date`, and get the last modified record **in each group**. Which could be achieved by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="string-join((code, date), '|')">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select='lastModifiedDateTime' order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want the results sorted by `code` and by `date`, then sort the groups:

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="string-join((code, date), '|')">
            <xsl:sort select='code' order="ascending"  data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:sort select='date' order="ascending" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select='lastModifiedDateTime' order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncnu9B9